# Disable deforming with armature

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, physics

I want to create an animation of a stormtrooper. For test purposes, I've set up a simple armature with some cubes as armor. When I parent them to the armature and move/rotate bones, the cubes get deformed. However, I only want them to follow the movement of the armature but not deform since the parts of the armor should be rigid.

If I turn off "deform" in the bone properties, the cubes just stop to follow the movement of the bones.

The .blend file is available here:[image]

It is just some cubes parented with automatic weight. I've made an colloection "old" with the same cubes but not parented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution! If you go into Weight paint for the disformed object, you can select individual bones. In my case, I selected the left upper arm bone and then painted the cube blue, so that a rotation of the arm bone doesn't affect the other cube